Wpf AdornerDecorator not updating the validation in a custom control
I have a custom step control (wizard) that steps between the items in it.
<ItemsControl x:Class="Cv.Desktop.Common.Controls.StepControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cv.Desktop.Common.Controls"
             xmlns:converters="http://completeview.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="root"
             UseLayoutRounding="True"
             Focusable="False"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:StepControl}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WizardButtons" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="NextButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource WizardButtons}">
                    <!-- Button Content Binding -->
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding NextButtonLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

                    <!-- Default IsEnabled based on MultiBinding -->
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- If ShowFinishLabel is True -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowFinishLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding FinishButtonLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding CurrentItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="20"
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowWizardButtons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="PreviousButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource WizardButtons}"
                            Content="{Binding PreviousButtonLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Click="HandlePrevious"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding CanMovePrevious, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowPreviousButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
                    <Button x:Name="NextButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource NextButtonStyle}"
                            Click="HandleNext"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding CanMoveNext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowNextButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
                    <Button x:Name="CancelButton"
                        Style="{StaticResource WizardButtons}"
                        Content="{Binding CancelButtonLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Click="HandleCancel"
                        IsCancel="True"
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowCancelButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>

And we use it like this:
<StepControl>
   <UserControlA />
   <UserControlB />
   <UserControlC />
</StepControl>

When we move from let's say go to UserControlB and there is a validation error, then we click the previous button and navigate to UserControlA then click to UserControlB the validation is still an issue, but we do not see the errors on the controls.
We've narrowed it down to - when we change the implementation to:
<StepControl>
   <UserControlA />
   <AdornerDecorator>
       <UserControlB />
   </AdornerDecorator>
   <UserControlC />
</StepControl>

The errors in the controls now work correctly.
I've tried to wrap the ContentPresenter in the AdornerDecorator and that doesn't work.
Thanks in advance!

There isn't enough information here for us to help. Can you add sample code of adorner decorators being used as well please? Also this xaml looks to be influenced by 3rd party providers, as this Content="{Binding CurrentItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" triggers my PTSD.

@XAMlMAX What you're saying here doesn't make sense. I did add the AdornerDecorators being used, and I have no idea what you mean by using a third-party provider, this is how you bind to the templated parent from the template.

Sorry, I should've put more info in my comment. What I meant was xaml with Adorner Decorators, I see that you have an example structure of how it was used. But I can't see where adorners with errors are used and how validations are triggered. BTW the top xaml you shared is that for StepControl or StepControl Container?

The validation is being triggered by IDataErrorInfo in a ViewModel, as far how they are triggered it really doesn't matter. the issue is that the AdornerDecorator associated with the StepControl isn't working. The top  is the stepcontrol.

I agree about how validation is triggered but only when you told me how you use it. I am not there so any assumptions you may have I won't know about them. Also you haven't provided how you use validation errors in xaml. A simple TextBox example would be great. Thanks

Have you managed to make any progress?

no, I just wrapped them with the AdornerDecorater and moved on.

ah fair enough, there is a limit on how many adorner decorator there can be in WPF app. I think the number is 120 or something like that. It will cause strange behaviour. Wonder if that has anything to do with your issue.
